# fbdialog unable to close

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

I am using the iOS static library project provided by Facebook developers for showing the screen, since there is a session timeout scenario, i have to close the screens when it is 15 mins. when user tries to share the post and if he just leaves it for 15 mins i am not able to close his view instead it just comes like a background after my piece of code which closes all the view (except the fbdialog). the problem is that i don't create fbdialog myself, instead i try that

```
facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:facebookAppId andDelegate:self] ;
```

the Facebook class creates the dialog and manages by itself, what has to be done to close the dialog whenever i want from my app to the static library.

Answer (score -1):

In your facebook sdk there must be the methods to close the dialog.
You have to use the delegates it provides in order to send messages to that methods. 
Find and implement them in your working class.

It must be something like FBDelegate or FBDialogDelegate, I am not sure, you could share a link to your facebook sdk to see it. 
I have worked with several FB sdks and they all ware different.